# Python Web-scraping youtube.com BeautifulSoup4 problem

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to get the author of every video on the YouTube homepage by web-scraping with BeautifulSoup4.

This is the chunk of HTML I am trying to navigate to.

```
<a class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string" spellcheck="false" href="/c/ApertureScience" dir="auto">Aperture</a>
```

With the link: `https://www.youtube.com/`

And I am trying to get the item "Aperture".

The problem is that I can't seem to navigate correctly to the data, I have been trying this:

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.youtube.com/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
for i in soup.find_all('a', class_='yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string'):
    print(i)
```

And nothing prints, I think it is because of the weird spaces in the class name but I don't know how to get around that.

If any ideas help, thank you!

Comment: Content is dynamically loaded. `urllib.request` doesn't run JavaScript.

Comment: This might be helpful based on what @gre_gor already mentioned. Looks as requersts-like alternative to Selenium. https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the syntax:

```
find_all('a',{'class' : 'yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string'})
```

and for the 'Aperture' use string or content or text.

And if the content is Dynamic, you could use Selenium.

Comment: Thank you I have realized from @gre_gor that the content is dynamic and I should use Selenium, thank you.